# iOS contacts sync against Ejabberd is taking 10+ minutes

Tags: ios, asynchronous, xmpp, ejabberd, import-contacts

I am searching for the users one by one based on the username and this is causing the process to take 10+ minutes with 250 contacts. I have also tried to send multiple requests asynchrounously so that multiple records could be processed at once. But I haven't been able to do so because it seems that XMPP framework for iOS would allow only one connection stream open at a time. Is there a way to batch check contacts?